# Sort By Int Property of Node List - Umbraco Razor

Tags: razor, umbraco

I am trying to sort a DynamicNodeList by a numeric property "cost". I've tried loads of different ways here but am completely at a loss:

```
var nodes = Model.AncestorOrSelf(1).Descendants().Where("NodeTypeAlias.Equals(\"Event\")").Where("Visible");

nodes = nodes.OrderBy("Int32.Parse(cost.Value)");
```

Gives me the error: No property or field 'Value' exists in type 'Func`2'

I've got a feeling this is as close as I've gotten! Does anybody have any clues on this?

EDIT:

OK I solved this by changing the NodeList:

```
var nodes = Model.AncestorOrSelf(1).Descendants().Where("NodeTypeAlias.Equals(\"Event\")").Where("Visible").Where("cost > 0");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nodes = nodes.OrderBy("cost");
```

...should work just fine.

Refer to [Umbraco Razor Feature Walkthrough – Part 4](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/3/1/umbraco-razor-feature-walkthrough-%E2%80%93-part-4.aspx) for more info on `OrderBy()`.

Comment: That's great thank you. I thought it should be this simple but it was giving an error saying it must be int32. I decided it must be pulling non-ints somewhere so am only pulling nodes which have a value in the cost property. Et voila, it worked!

Comment: Ah, good point. If there isn't a value, it will return a blank string, otherwise it will return an int.

Comment: That's strange, as trying to get the nodes with .Where("cost != \"\"") won't work - it only works as above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
Dictionary<DynamicNode, int> myVar = new Dictionary<DynamicNode, int>();
foreach(var node in nodes)
{
    myVar.Add(node,node.GetPropertyValue("cost");
}
```

and then sort that. That's the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues when sorting on something more than a single item or something that isn't simple.  In those cases, I convert it to a List or DynamicNode objects and use the Sort method with a delegate.

Something like this:

```
possibleListings.Sort(delegate(DynamicNode x, DynamicNode y)
{       
  ... perform sorting logic
});
```

Then you can do Int32.TryParse() calls or whatever you need inside the delegate.